# Want to add Number of Products added by each shop manager in users list

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, users

[image]

Actually I want to count how many products have added by each shop manager
So thats why I Want to add Number of produts column here

Can anyone Help me in it???

Comment: Is there no one who can solve it?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code.
It shows the number of products of each user, exactly what you wanted!!!

```
// create tab row in users page
add_filter( 'manage_users_columns', 'pre_modify_user_table' );
function pre_modify_user_table( $column ) {
    $column['pCount'] = 'product count';
    return $column;
}

// display user product count
add_filter( 'manage_users_custom_column', 'pre_modify_user_table_row', 10, 3 );
function pre_modify_user_table_row( $val, $column_name, $user_id ) {
    switch ($column_name) {
        case 'pCount' :
            $args = array(
                'author'     =>  $user_id,
                'post_type'  => 'product'
            );
            $author_posts = get_posts( $args );
            $val =  count($author_posts);
        default:
    }
    return $val;
}
```

The image shows the result:

[image]